# Separate input in scanf()?

Tags: c, scanf

I want to separate a 5 digit number taken in through `scanf()` into three different variables. The first variable should have the first digit, the second should have the second 2 digits, and the third should have the last 2 digits.

I was thinking of something like this:

```
int num1;
int num2;
int num3;
scanf(%1d%2d%2d, &num1, &num2, &num3);
```

However, this doesn't work: it assigns the last two digits to every variable.

Is there any way to do this without separating the number after scanning in all 5 digits?

Comment: @gsamaras I was just wondering if scanf() has the capability to take care of it. I don't mind using the modulus operator to do it, this was just out of curiosity.

Comment: You could read the first two digits as `char` and the rest as `int`.

Comment: @user3121023 you're right. I also realized I was doing this in the context of a union, so it wouldn't work there. But if I switch to struct it should work. Thanks!

Comment: Which code did "*assigns the last two digits to every variable.*"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
scanf(%1d%2d%2d, &num1, &num2, &num3);
```

to this:

```
scanf("%1d%2d%2d", &num1, &num2, &num3);
```

since you forgot to use the double quotes.

See this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int num1, num2, num3;
    scanf("%1d%2d%2d", &num1, &num2, &num3);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", num1 ,num2, num3);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
> 12345
1 23 45
```

See it for yourself in this <kbd>[Live Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/qQuKqjrM0DFokZxS)</kbd>

Comment: Oh! man This really is a syntax error? Everyone thought  OP is knowingly ignoring the quotes`" "`.

Comment: @kiranBiradar simplicity is a virtue.

Comment: plus one  for really trying out the problem rather doubting the `C`.